# Failing to stroke() the UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I wish to create a perfectly rounded rect (Circle) and paint it on the screen. I have tested my code in playground, and it successfully paints the UIBezierPath. It doesn't, however, successfully paint it in the iOS simulator. Here's the code I've been working on:

```
    class Circles {

        //Defining the rounded rect (Circle)
        func roundRect(radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

            //Creating the rounded the rectangle (Circle)
            var roundedRect = UIBezierPath()
            roundedRect.addArcWithCenter(CGPointZero, radius: radius,
                startAngle: 0, endAngle: angle ,
                clockwise: true)

            return roundedRect
        }


        //Drawing the Bezier Path (Circle)
        func drawRect(rect: UIBezierPath){

            rect.moveToPoint(self.point)
            UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
            rect.stroke()
        }

        //Giving the rounded rect (Circle) it's position
        var point = CGPointMake(500, 500)
    }
    //Giving the rounded rect (Circle) it's size
    var newRect = Circles().roundRect(200.0, angle: 7)

    //Drawing the rounded rect (Circle)
    Circles().drawRect(newRect)
```

I have seen some other posts with similar problems from a few years back, however they were in Objective-C, I tried translating but it was not of any use. I've also tried several other methods of painting the path on the screen but, again sadly, it was of no use. I tested it to make sure the functions are working with println statements, the issue is I don't know why the stroke is not activating. Thanks for reading, -Zach.

Here's the updated version using what Mike said:

```
class CircleView: UIView {
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    // Creating the rectangle's size
    var newRect = Circles().roundRect(200.0, angle: 7)

    //Drawing the rectangle
    Circles().drawRect(newRect)
}


//Holding all to do with the circle
class Circles {

    //Defining the rounded rect (Circle)
    func roundRect(radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

        //Creating the rounded rect (Circle)
        var roundedRect = UIBezierPath()
        roundedRect.addArcWithCenter(CGPointZero, radius: radius,
            startAngle: 0, endAngle: angle ,
            clockwise: true)

        return roundedRect
    }


    //Drawing the Bezier Path (Circle)
    func drawRect(rect: UIBezierPath){

        rect.moveToPoint(self.point)
        UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
        UIColor.blackColor().setFill()
        rect.stroke()
        rect.fill()
    }

    //Giving the rounded rect (Circle) it's position
    var point = CGPointMake(500, 500)
    }

}



class ViewController: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Generating the background
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "normalpaper.jpg"))

    let circleView = CircleView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(circleView)

}
```

Comment: It works for me in the simulator with Xcode6 GM. How are you calling `Circles.drawRect(...)` when you test it in the simulator?

Comment: What do you mean by how are you calling `Circles.drawRect(...)`? I'm calling it `Circles().drawRect(newRect)` at the bottom in the code example. I'm also using 6.1 beta not 6 GM

@Mike S

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have said: **Where** are you calling `Circles.drawRect` when you test this code in the simulator? In a custom UIView's `drawRect` function maybe?

Comment: @Mike S I'm calling it inside of the class and where I'm calling it is inside of the viewDidLoad function inside of the UIViewController. Where should I call it?

Comment: @MikeS Sorry, just realized that sentence is retarded, I'm calling it inside of the viewDidLoad function. The class that contains the drawRect function is also inside of the viewDidLoad function. Where should they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, you're calling `drawRect` from a `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` function. You don't have a valid drawing context there, so that's not going to work.

The easiest way to make this work is to create a `UIView` subclass with its own `drawRect` function which calls `Circle().drawRect(...)` and add that as a subview of your `UIViewController`'s `view`.

**Here's an example of this:**

***Note:** I've made the custom view transparent by setting `circleView.opaque = false` so that the background you mentioned in the comments shows through.*

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // I just copied this directly from the original question
        var newRect = Circles().roundRect(200.0, angle: 7)
        Circles().drawRect(newRect)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a new CircleView that's the same size of this 
        // view controller's bounds and add it to the view hierarchy
        let circleView = CircleView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        circleView.opaque = false
        self.view.addSubview(circleView)
    }
}
```

***Note:** If you're going to be doing custom drawing, I highly recommend you read [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156). It'll teach you all the basics you need to make it work.*

Comment: I will read that guide soon, for the time being, I updated my original post to the current code I have, creating a custom UIView class. However, the output, is still the same. It does not print the rect so far as I can tell. It does occur to me that the `Circles().drawRect(newRect)` in the `func drawRect` is never being called. (Tested with a `println()` statement) How would I set it so it is always called similar to how `viewDidLoad` is always called?

Comment: I don't see anything in your `viewDidLoad` function in the code you added to the question...

Comment: Sorry, accidentally cut it out, correcting it now:

Also, when I add the thing you added in viewDidLoad, my background fails to load.

I'm using a custom image background, so I scratched out the white background you added.

Comment: I modified the code in my answer to make the view transparent so that your background shows through. I think that should fix things.

Comment: I noticed that it was creating a new instance of view that I should edit, so I just changed circleView's background instead. I have also gained the knowledge of creating custom views to add to the heirarchy. It works brilliantly, thank you very much good sir.